# Use specific columns and lines numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a matrix where the first column and line are composed by strings and rest of it is floats:

```
[["City","Score1","Score2","Score3"],
["Berkley",23,432,321],
["Ohio",3,432,54],
["Columbia",123,432,53]]
```

I just need to make another matrix to store the floats.
It would look like this:

```
[[23,432,321],
[3,432,54],
[123,432,53]]
```

Comment: Those aren't floats, they're ints. What have you tried?

Comment: In all further questions please tag [numpy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numpy) if your matrix is a numpy array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using numpy:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([["City","Score1","Score2","Score3"],
                ["Berkley",23,432,321],
                ["Ohio",3,432,54],
                ["Columbia",123,432,53]])

new_arr = arr[1:, 1:].astype(float)
```

**NOTE:** In your example those are ints not floats, but I've still used floats here